# What am i doing wrong? (Python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a basic number guessing game as I've just started coding. I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I tried looking on the forums here but I failed to find an answer. If anyone could tell me what I'm doing wrong I`d greatly appreciate it!

```
import random
num = random.randint(1, 10)

while true:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))

    if guess is == num
        print("you got it!")
            break

    else:
        print("try again!")
```

ERROR:

```
break
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: clue `if guess is == num` doesn't make sense also if you received errors then include the errors. You probably want `if guess == num:` note removal of `is` and addition of colon `:`

Comment: Thank you I fixed that error. Do you mind explaining why the colon is neccesary ? I now have a different error:
  break
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Consult the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html)

Comment: Ok thanks for your help.

Comment: There are many things wrong with the code; Python can only report the first problem (and most of them can only happen when the code actually runs).

Answer (score 0):

It should be `if guess == num:`. You don't need the `is` and you need to put `:` on the if. Also, the `true` should be `True` and `break` has to have the correct ident.

```
import random
num = random.randint(1, 10)

while True:
    guess = int(input("Guess a number between 1 and 10: "))

    if guess == num:
        print("you got it!")
        break

    else:
        print("try again!")
```